# How to create a swift ios framework that using pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm tryin to create a framework , and then use .framework file in other projects. I need to use other pods in my framework like Alamofire. But when I add pods into my framework, it doesn't work on another project.

Comment: Did u get any answer ?

Comment: @kishor0011 Unfortunately no!!